# Determine amount multiplied in sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose you have **n** , and **r** (result) = some value *less than n* (**ltn**) multiplied by **4**, plus what's left of n after subtracting ltn (n - ltn).

Eg. **n** = 60; (r) = 25 (ltn) + (60 (n) - 25 (ltn) = 35) = **135**.

Now, if I know the values of **n (60)** and **r (135)**, is there a formula to determine the value of **ltn**?

I can "bruteforce" it by taking **r** (135) find the highest number that divides by 4 without fractions (132 / 4 = 33) and then deduct that from n (60 - 33 = 27) and add the left over (27) to 133 = 159. Well that's way higher than 135, so let's move down to 128 (next number divisible by 4) etc... but is there a simpler way? Thanks...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It gives a linear equation.

$r=4l+n-l $

$r=3l+n $

$l=\frac {r-n}{3}$

Comment: Brillian!
Based on your equation I was able to take it a step further, where $r=4l+2(n-l) $. Eg. $r=170 $. 
I can use $l=\frac {r-2n}{2}$ Makes sense?

Comment: Why is someone downvoting without even commenting?

Comment: @scrollup I don't know.

Comment: @scrollup yes you can use that